# What is the difference between readonly and readwrite in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

Can any one tell me the difference between `readonly` and `readwrite` properties in the iPhone SDK?

Comment: Did you read the documentation or even google this before you asked?

Comment: -1 this question shows absolutely no sign of any prior research at all.  A tip for Googling answers in future:  put *site:developer.apple.com* as part of the search query, then all results not on that site will be filtered out. e.g: *site:developer.apple.com readonly readwrite*

Comment: Yes i googled it but i didn't get the correct information. If you have the link Please share which can give me the right info about these property

Comment: Just to note, this is now the top result for "objective c readwrite", so any requests to 'google it' are going to lead here.

Comment: @KirbyTodd funny how that works out eh?

Answer (score 22):

**readwrite**
   Indicates that the property should be treated as read/write. This attribute is the default.
Both a *getter* and *setter* method are required in the `@implementation` block. If you use the `@synthesize` directive in the implementation block, the *getter* and *setter* methods are synthesized.

**readonly**
   Indicates that the property is read-only.
If you specify readonly, only a *getter* method is required in the `@implementation` block. If you use the `@synthesize` directive in the `@implementation` block, only the *getter* method is synthesized. Moreover, if you attempt to assign a value using the dot syntax, you get a compiler error.

[For more visit this reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon : Thanks Doc that's better way to give the answer...:)

Comment: ... and you can change a readonly into a readwrite in a class extension, thus allowing a property to be publically readonly and privately readwrite.